# FreeBSD em0 fallback to 100Mbit Fast Ethernet on HP/Compaq DC7700

Tags: networking, drivers, freebsd, openbsd

I have a couple of HP DC7700CMT machines, each with its own integrated Intel 82566DM GbE LAN port, shown in dmesg as Intel PRO/1000 and using the *em* driver. I recently discovered that FreeBSD doesn't handle this LAN port correctly, as it is not able to use it as 1000baseT. During boot, when the **em0** device is detected it is shown as 1000baseT, but by the time I log in, the device is fallen back to 100baseTX. If I manually force it back to gigabit,
    **ifconfig em0 media 1000baseT**
the connection gets dropped immediately, led on the switch port goes out, and the device behaves like it has no cable connected.
Each time I reset the media to autoselect,
    **ifconfig em0 media autoselect**
the device gets properly set to 1000baseT first -for just enough time to query the adapter status and see that it is set to gigabit- then within a second it changes to 100baseTX Fast ethernet.
I have tested it on 3 such HP machines. Same behaviour on each computer.
I have also tested it with multiple UTP cables. Even a short, high quality STP one. Same behaviour.
I have tried 3 different switches. One 8 port D-Link Desktop GbE switch, one TP-Link GbE router with built-in 4 port GbE switch, and one HP ProCurve 2810 GbE switch with 24 ports. Same behaviour with each switch.
And finally, I have tried multiple operating systems. FreeBSD 9.3R/amd64, 9.2R/amd64, 9.2R/i386, 8.4R/amd64, 7.4R/amd64, all dropping my em0 device back to 100baseT. OpenBSD 5.2/i386 also drops the em0 device to 100baseT, so it must be an em driver code shared between FreeBSD and OpenBSD. Tried a couple of Linux Live CDs, and they all properly handle this LAN port at gigabit speed with no sign of trouble. And finally, Win7 also uses the same hardware at gigabit speed without any problems.
So I concluded that the problem is in the FreeBSD em driver code.
I would like to know if others have similar experience with the *em* driver under FreeBSD, or if anyone has an *em* device that does work as 1000baseT.

Do any of you use a similar hardware?
Do you experience your *em* device falling back to Fast Ethernet?
Do any of you use an *em* device that works properly as GbE?

For reference, here is an example of what happens on FreeBSD 9.2R, regardless of booting amd64 and i386.
The time between one command and the next is always just the 2 to 5 seconds it takes me to type in that particular command and hit enter at my usual typing speed. For this example, I did not use the up-arrow to get an earlier command back from history. Each command was typed in.

```
            Script started on Sun Aug 31 11:48:04 2014
            root@hp:~ # ifconfig em0
            em0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
                options=4219b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,TSO4,WOL_MAGIC,VLAN_HWTSO>
                ether 00:0f:fe:82:30:37
                inet 10.25.74.105 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.25.74.255
                nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
                media: Ethernet autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
                status: active
            root@hp:~ # ifconfig em0 media autoselect
            root@hp:~ # ifconfig em0
            em0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
                options=4219b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,TSO4,WOL_MAGIC,VLAN_HWTSO>
                ether 00:0f:fe:82:30:37
                inet 10.25.74.105 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.25.74.255
                nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
                media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
                status: active
            root@hp:~ # ifconfig em0
            em0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
                options=4219b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,TSO4,WOL_MAGIC,VLAN_HWTSO>
                ether 00:0f:fe:82:30:37
                inet 10.25.74.105 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.25.74.255
                nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
                media: Ethernet autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
                status: active
            root@hp:~ # ifconfig em0 media 1000baseT
            root@hp:~ # ifconfig em0
            em0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
                options=4219b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,TSO4,WOL_MAGIC,VLAN_HWTSO>
                ether 00:0f:fe:82:30:37
                inet 10.25.74.105 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.25.74.255
                nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
                media: Ethernet 1000baseT (autoselect)
                status: no carrier
            root@hp:~ # ifconfig em0
            em0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
                options=4219b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,TSO4,WOL_MAGIC,VLAN_HWTSO>
                ether 00:0f:fe:82:30:37
                inet 10.25.74.105 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.25.74.255
                nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
                media: Ethernet 1000baseT (autoselect)
                status: no carrier
            root@hp:~ # ifconfig em0 media autoselect
            root@hp:~ # ifconfig em0
            em0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
                options=4219b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,TSO4,WOL_MAGIC,VLAN_HWTSO>
                ether 00:0f:fe:82:30:37
                inet 10.25.74.105 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.25.74.255
                nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
                media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
                status: active
            root@hp:~ # ifconfig em0
            em0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
                options=4219b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,TSO4,WOL_MAGIC,VLAN_HWTSO>
                ether 00:0f:fe:82:30:37
                inet 10.25.74.105 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.25.74.255
                nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
                media: Ethernet autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
                status: active
            root@hp:~ # exit
            exit

            Script done on Sun Aug 31 11:49:58 2014
```

Any comment or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I guess the majority of people would have no problem. Including me, naturally. ;) I have a dedicated 82574L card, though.

Comment: Excellent, Daniel. I was hoping to get some feedback with this sort of confirmation. Is yours a PCI card? Or is that a 1x PCIe, 4x PCIe ?